# Gawk regular expression for days in month

Tags: regex, gawk

Im writing regular expression that accepts days in months `([0-3])([0-9])`. How to change it so it will only accept proper amount of days from 1 to 31, but not 37 like mine... i tried alternation |, but i don't know how to include first group into it. 
`([0-2])([0-9])|(3)([0-1])` does not work

How to change it so i will have still 2 groups and proper dates?

edit: 2 groups, not 4

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this :

```
(0)([1-9])|(1|2)([0-9])|(3)(0|1)
```

[image: Regular expression image]

**DEMO** [Match numbers between 01 and 31 only](http://regexr.com?3578c)

Answer (score 0):

`(0[1-9]|[12][0-9]|3[01])`

This accepts values between 0-31 in one group, but does not care about about that February has no days as 30,31.

Sorry, misread it. 
If you want to get the values in two groups you have to use negative lookahead like so:

`([0-2]|3(?![^0-1]))([0-9])`

**But** I think gawk does not support this.